# Как поменять шрифт у бейджа в таббаре?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

Каким образом для iOS10+ можно установить шрифт у бейджа в таббаре и сменить цвет шрифта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

**Установить шрифт и цвет текста**

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setBadgeTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor],
                                                     NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Kefa" size:30.f],
                                                     } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Установка цвета**

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setBadgeColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

**Установка TabBar**

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                     NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Kefa" size:30.f]
                                                     }
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor],
                                                     NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Kefa" size:30.f]
                                                     }
                                         forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще хочу порекомендовать библиотеку: https://github.com/mikeMTOL/UIBarButtonItem-Badge

Я ее использую в своих проектах. Умеет устанавливать бейджи как на элементы navigationBar, так и для обычных кнопок.